# JFXComboBox does not show default set value

Tags: javafx, java-8

I am using a JFXComboBox to show user group a user can be allocated to. The roles are fetched from the DB.  Fetching of the `role`list is done by `getRoleNameList()`. I populate the JFXComboBox as below:

**Populate userGroup JFXComboBox**

```
// Populate userGroup JFXComboBox
ObservableList<Role> roles = rdc.getRoleNameList();
roles.sort(Comparator.comparing(Role::getCode)); // Sort the list
uGroupComboBox.getItems().setAll(roles);
uGroupComboBox.setVisibleRowCount(5);
```

**JFXCombobox FXML:**

```
<JFXComboBox id="userGroup" fx:id="uGroupComboBox" focusColor="#07595a" 
    layoutX="245.0" layoutY="256.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="148.0"
    promptText="Select User Group" styleClass="jfx-combo-box" 
    unFocusColor="#48aaad">
```

**The model below is for Roles:**

```
package records.models;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class Role {
    private final StringProperty code;
    private final StringProperty name;

    public Role() {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        this.code = new SimpleStringProperty();
    }

    public Role(String name) {
        String codename = StringUtils.capitalize(name.toLowerCase().trim());
        this.code = new SimpleStringProperty(codename);

        name = name.toLowerCase().trim();
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
    }

    // name
    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        if (name != null) {
            name = name.toLowerCase().trim();
        }
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    // @return code
    public String getCode() {
        return code.get();
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        if (code != null) {
            code = StringUtils.capitalize(code.toLowerCase().trim());
        }
        this.code.set(code);
    }

    public StringProperty codeProperty() {
        return code;
    }

    public Role getRole(){
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.code.get();
    }
}
```

When I fetch from the DB the user group the user is assigned to, the data is not displayed:

```
String uRole = role.get("role") == null ? null : 
    role.get("role").toString();
user.setRole(uRole);
// Create the role that is fetched from DB
Role uGroup = new Role(uRole);
// uGroupComboBox.setValue(uGroup);
uGroupComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(uGroup);
```

This does not work. As you can see, the field is not null. If it were, I would show the prompt text

[image: This does not work. As you can see, the field is not null. If it were, I would show the prompt text]

However, the JFXComboBox list is successfully populated:

[image]

If I do `System.out.println(uGroupComboBox.getValue());` it shows the correct value eg. *if the user group is `Nurse`, the statement returns `Nurse`*

Why does the JFXComboBox not display the value?

Comment: You listed jfxtras as a tag, but JFXComboBox is part of the JFoenix project. https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/blob/master/jfoenix/src/main/java/com/jfoenix/controls/JFXComboBox.java

Comment: Are you setting a cell factory anywhere?

Comment: @James_D Not using cell factory for the ComboBox. Do I need to?

Comment: Thanks for the correction tbeernot

Comment: @Tav No: just trying to guess why the cells in the popup might be displayed differently to the cell in the combo itself (i.e. the cell that displays the selected value). Does it display the correct thing if you choose something in the combo (i.e. is it an issue with setting the selection, or a general issue with the combo box display)?

Comment: @James_D It displays the correctly if I select a value from the list. Been at it for 3hours and I can't quite figure out why it won't take the set value.

Comment: @Tav, I think I have the same or similar problem with JFXComboBox. Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your Role object with its StringProperty properties. Let me explain myself.

if you just take :

```
static void main(String[] args){

    StringProperty codeName = new SimpleStringProperty("codename");
    StringProperty codeNameSameValue = new SimpleStringProperty("codename");
    boolean isthesame = codeName.equals(codeNameSameValue);
    System.out.println("isthesame:"+isthesame);
    boolean isReallyTheSame = codeName.get().equals(codeNameSameValue.get());
    System.out.println("isReallyTheSame:"+isReallyTheSame);

}
```

You will  see on you console output

```
isthesame:false
isReallyTheSame:true
```

Ok it is still not the answer to your question but for you Role class default equals method that will be comparing object properties like my first comparison:

```
comparingStringProperty.equals(comparedStringProperty);  
...
```

To solve the problem you need to override the equals method in the Role object. For example with something like that:
i

```
mport java.util.Objects;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class Role {

    private final StringProperty code;
    private final StringProperty name;

    /*Constructors, setters and getter are deleted for clarity */
    ....

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.code.get();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        // If the object is compared with itself then return true   
        if (o == this) {
            return true;
        }

        /* Check if o is an instance of Role or not 
          "null instanceof [type]" also returns false */
        if (!(o instanceof Role)) {
            return false;
        }

        // typecast o to Role so that we can compare data members  
        Role r = (Role) o;

        return (r.name.get() == this.name.get() || r.name.get() != null && r.name.get().equals(this.name.get()));
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name.get(), code.get());
    }
}
```

This equals method will be use during the call :

```
uGroupComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(uGroup);
```

And voila!